# Write a program to run 2 processes and run ls in 1st and ps in another

Tags: c++, linux

Im trying to write a code in C++ for Linux that runs 2 processes, ls in the first one and ps in the second one. I want to use fork() to create additional processes. I also want to add something to handle a situtation where fork is returned with an error. This is the code I have right now:

```
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/stat.h>
    #include <fcntl.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <unistd.h>

    int main()
    {
    close(1);
    open("output.txt");
    execlp("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);
    execvp("ps","ps",NULL);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: There must be several thousands of tutorials and examples on how to do this, all over the Internet. What kind of research have you made?

Comment: Open your terminal with `ctrl+alt+T`, and use the `man` command to read about `fork` and its return value (on success and on error).

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion comes from this:

```
execlp("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);
```

That's perfectly fine code, but you don't know it does. It loads the given program and transfers execution to it. Any code after that is not executed. It's basically kind of like a big GOTO statement.

What you need to do is fork and exec.

```
if (fork()) {
    execlp("/bin/ls","ls",NULL);
}
else {
    execvp("ps","ps",NULL);
}
```

Note that I have no faith at all that your output file will have the output in a sane fashion. At the very least, you should open in append mode, possibly O_TRUNC | O_APPEND.